# Como definir um valor padrão de uma coluna no Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express.js, sequelize-js

Estou usando o Sequelize (v5.0+) com NodeJS (com Express). Eu quero que para a coluna `status` no meu banco de dados tenha o valor padrão (`defaultValue`) como `true`.

**Migration**

```js
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      status: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: true,
      }
    }
  down: (queryInterface) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  }
}
```

**Model**

```js
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

class User extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init({
      status: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
    }
  );
}

export default User;
```

**Controller**

```js
import User from '../models/User';

class UserController {
  async store(req, res) {
    const { id, status } = await User.create(req.body);

    return res.json({ message: `${id}, Status: ${status}, user register successful` });
  }

    return res.json({ users });
  }
}

export default new Users();
```

Quando eu envio a minha requisição sem indicar o `status`, me é retornado o seguinte erro:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: null value in column "status" violates not-null constraint
```

Se eu coloco no corpo da requisição o valor do campo `status` funciona normalmente.

Já dei uma olhada na documentação do Sequelize, mas não achei nada lá que detalhasse com clareza esse ponto.

Comment: Você já tem dados na tabela com valor nulo? Ou esse problema é só ao inserir um dado novo?

Comment: É só ao inserir um dado novo. 
Eu poderia simplesmente passar no controller o valor padrão, mas o mais ideal seria que mesmo que eu não passasse valor nenhum seja na requisição ou no controller o banco já definisse por padrão como 1 ou true.

Comment: Pronto, coloquei lá. Eu passo no corpo da requisição basicamente só o status, desse jeito funciona, o status é salvo no banco de dados.
Porém quando eu não passo ele vazio dá esse erro.  Mesmo que eu passasse vazio eu queria que o banco salvasse com o valor padrão.

Comment: Quando você passa vazio significa `{ "status" : "" }` ou o body fica `{}`?

Comment: o body fica `{}` eu omito o campo status no meu body

Comment: Tem uma pergunta relacionada no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36194613/8839059), mas não sei se vai te ajudar... Consegue confirmar em algum gerenciador de BD se o `status` um valor *default*? Eu uso o HeidiSQL pra confirmar algumas coisas pq o Sequelize é meio estranho as vezes hehe

Comment: [Coluna Status](https://i1.lensdump.com/i/jQXQRF.png), o SDBG que estou usando é o DBeaver.
Nossa cara, consegui resolver. Dei uma olhada nessa pergunta que você mandou.
Como foi dito lá, eu inverti a ordem e coloquei o `defaultValue: 1` em cima do `allowNull: false` e deu certo.
Posso colocar a resposta ou você quer fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas deixe a propriedade `defaultValue` acima da propriedade `allowNull` na *migration* de Usuário.

Muito obrigado pelo seu tempo e ajuda @rafael-tavares

***Migration* de Usuário**

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      status: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
+        defaultValue: true,
+        allowNull: false,
      }
    }
  down: (queryInterface) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  }
}
```